# How can i get variable out of a class?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to get variable out of a class but seems that I am not doing it correctly.

Here is code for `upload_inc.php`

```
class upload
{
    var $directory_name;
    var $max_filesize;
    var $error;

    var $user_tmp_name;
    var $user_file_name;
    var $user_file_size;
    var $user_file_type;
    var $user_full_name;


    function set_directory($dir_name =".")
    {
     $this->directory_name = $dir_name;

    }

    function set_max_size($max_file = 2000000)
    {
     $this->max_filesize = $max_file;
    }

    function error()
    {
     return $this->error;
    }

    function is_ok()
    {
     if(isset($this->error))
      return FALSE;
     else
      return TRUE;
    }

    function set_tmp_name($temp_name)
    {
     $this->user_tmp_name = $temp_name;  
    }

    function set_file_size($file_size)
    {
     $this->user_file_size = $file_size;
    }

    function set_file_type($file_type)
    {
     $this->user_file_type = $file_type;

    }

    function set_file_name($file)
    {
        $this->user_file_name = $file;
        $this->user_full_name = $this->directory_name."/".$this->user_file_name;
        echo $this->user_full_name;
    }

    function start_copy()
    {
        if(!isset($this->user_file_name))
         $this->error = "You must define filename!";

        if ($this->user_file_size <= 0)
         $this->error = "File size error (0): $this->user_file_size KB<br>";

        if ($this->user_file_size > $this->max_filesize)
         $this->error = "File size error (1): $this->user_file_size KB<br>";

        if($this->user_file_type != "image/jpeg")
           $this->error = "the image must be jpeg extension";

        if (!isset($this->error))
        {
            $filename = basename($this->user_file_name);

            if (!empty($this->directory_name)) 
                $destination = $this->user_full_name;
            else 
                $destination = $filename;

            if(!is_uploaded_file($this->user_tmp_name))
             $this->error = "File " . $this->user_tmp_name . " is not uploaded correctly.";

            if (!move_uploaded_file ($this->user_tmp_name,$destination))
             $this->error = "Impossible to copy " . $this->user_file_name. " from " . $userfile . "to destination directory.";
             echo 'test file' . $userfile;
        }
    }

}
```

In the second page after uploading the file, I am trying to get only the file name. Then, I can store the file name in my database. Here is my code.

`upload.php`

```
// Defining Class
$uploaded = new upload;

// Set Max Size
$uploaded->set_max_size(350000);

// Set Directory
$uploaded->set_directory("data");

// Do not change
// Set Temp Name for upload, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] 
$uploaded->set_tmp_name($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

// Set file size, 
$uploaded->set_file_size($_FILES['file']['size']);

// Set File Type, 
$uploaded->set_file_type($_FILES['file']['type']);

// Set File Name, 
$uploaded->set_file_name($_FILES['file']['name']);


// Start Copy Process
$uploaded->start_copy();


// Control File is uploaded or not
// If there is error write the error message
if($uploaded->is_ok()){
 echo "successfully loaded <br />";
}else{
 echo $uploaded->error()."<br>";
}this should show only file name but it does not.
```

Comment: Do you really not have a `;` after the echo statement?

Comment: ops sorry there is ; after echo but still i get this error msg Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /home/test/domains/skyup.nl/public_html/upload_Class/upload.php on line 69

Answer (score 3):

Why do you expect the class to contain the filename in the member variable? Where are you assigning it to the member variable? All I see is that you are creating a new class (besides, it should be "new upload();", you missed the parentheses) whose member variables are not initalized. So you  get a null value when doing the echo, which is the expected result.
What do you try to achieve? If you want the class-instance to "keep" its values across different request-response cycles you would have to store the whole instance somewhere (seralizing it) and restoring it when needed (unserializing it). You could also simply store the filename in the session if that is all you need.

Comment: You are not required to have the `()` when declaring all objects. http://ideone.com/6Jnhc

Comment: @Jared Farrish, in particular, they may be omitted when the constructor does not require any arguments.

Comment: @erisco - Thank you for clarifying that a method call requires the use of parentheses. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but as far as the error you're currently getting... You'll need to create a constructor for your `Upload` class that accepts a value for `$user_file_name` and then set it.  Alternatively you can use `set_file_name()` before trying to use the `$user_file_name` var.  As it stands right now that value is never being set, which is why you're getting an error on your call to `echo`.

Also, as others have said, you should really go back and accept answers to your questions if you found them helpful.

Comment: that is strange i did comment and sent a thanks msg for each of my quesion which was answered. i am going to check once again

Answer (score 0):

Main thing which you need is good IDE, with smart code highlighting :)
I recommend PhpStorm (*not ideal, but best at this moment, I hope somebody will create something better*).

In your code $userfile are not defined. You can define this variable:
`$userfile = $this->user_tmp_name;`
in function `start_copy()`.